# подходящий срез в питоне

Tags: python, алгоритм, срез

Мне необходимо обеспечить правильный срез строки
К примеру, у меня есть строка  `str = "((a.b)|c)"` и мне нужно сделать срез от скобки до скобки сначала `(a.b)|c`, а потом -- `a.b`
Как это можно сделать? Была идея взятия индексов закрывающейся и открывающейся скобок, и потом с помощью срезов брать скобку с индексом [0] и [-1].  Скобок может быть разное от количество, но всегда парное открытых и закрытых

Comment: _"Скобок может быть разное от количество"_, — приведите, пожалуйста, такой пример. Вы можете сделать это, нажав кнопку [edit]. Меня интересует, могут ли быть между скобками какие-то данные. В качестве идеи могу предложить рекурсию.

Comment: Может имеет смысл воспользоваться регулярными выражениями ?
В питоне есть встроенная библиотека `re` для работы с регулярными варажениями. Регулярные выражения позваляет находить совпадения в тексте следуя определенным паттернам, например, как в данном случае, с использованием текста внутри скобок, самый простой пример `\((.*)\)` - будет искать любой текст внутри скобок. Для более глубокого ознакомления можно обратиться к [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Comment: @AndreyRF, тут лучше дать более развернутый ответ. Напишите пример кода или дайте выдержку на документацию

Comment: @AndreyRF, нет, не имеет. Они тут совершенно не в тему.

Comment: да регулярки не решат проблему сопоставления скобок. я бы рекомендовал рекурсию или цикл со стэком.

Comment: @eri, какая ещё рекурсия со стеком, когда простой цикл со счётчиком?

Comment: @Qwertiy если бы нужно было просто проверить валидность, то достаточно было бы цикла и счетчика вложенности (по идее). А так как нужно возвращать срезы, то нужно помнить индексы открывающихся скобок. Причем из-за того что нужно возвращать от более широкого до более узкого среза, то скорее всего нужно будет хранить список пар начало/конец среза (открытой/закрытой скобки), и потом обходить его в нужном порядке.

Comment: @insolor, просили один срез, а не список срезов. Если нужно парсить что-то,то эти срезы вообще не нужны - там другой алгоритм.

Comment: @Qwertiy, насколько я понял вопрос, нужна именно **последовательность** срезов: сначала общий, потом вложенные в него, и т.д.: `"нужно сделать срез от скобки до скобки сначала (a.b)|c, а потом -- a.b"`.

Comment: @insolor, хм.. ну так тоже можно. А я,значит, читаю невнимательно.